# Assessing measurement accuracy and precision

Tags: st.statistics, linear-algebra

I have been asked to assess the accuracy and precision of a new measurement method (Let's call it method B).  This new method is compared to an existing one (A) that has its own specifications in terms of stdev of a single measurement. What we do is to measure several samples with method A and then with method B. Since A is very expensive, only one A measurement per case is available. Method B is cheaper, so we measure each sample with method B for several times.

Another problem is that we are unable to find samples that would span across the entire legal measurement range, resulting in several samples in the first quartile of the range, several in the last range quartile and almost no in between.

How can I assess the accuracy and precision of method B? Any help or link will be appreciated.

Thank you very much

P.S. This is not a homework.

P.P.S I admit, I don't know statistics well

Comment: When you say method A "has its own specifications in terms of stdev of a single measurement", do you mean that A is known to satisfy those specifications?  Is A unbiased in the sense of giving the right answer on average?

Comment: ....and also, is the standard deviation of the answer given by A independent of the quantity being measured?  (This would imply sometimes giving a negative number even when the answer is always positive; that's part of the downside of unbiasedness.)  Or could it be that the standard deviation of the logarithm of A is independent of the size of the quantity being measured?

Answer (score 1):

I have asked this question on Allstat and currently considering adopting [this suggestion](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=ind1007&L=ALLSTAT&F=&S=&P=61358)

> From your question I understand that
>   there is only one measurement per case
>   with method A. This means that
>   assessing the agreement between A and
>   B reduces to showing  that the mean
>   differences between A and B
>   (accuracy)($\overline{\Delta_{A,B}}
> > \approx 0$) is as close to 0 as
>   possible and the standard deviation of
>   these differences (precision) is as
>   low as possible.
>
> I also learn that the measurements you
>   take can take values between two
>   numbers. This might lead to the
>   situation where the distribution of
>   $\Delta_{A,B}$ is far from being
>   normal. On the other hand, you have
>   multiple measurements of several
>   cases. Now, here comes the tricky
>   part. Assume that the real mean
>   difference between A and B readings is
>   $\mu$ with standard deviation of
>   $\sigma$. We may treat those multiple
>   measurements as different samplings
>   from the overall distribution. Each
>   sampling $i$ has its own mean
>   difference $\overline{\Delta_i}$.
>   According to the central limit
>   theorem, the mean of means
>   ($\mu_{\overline{\Delta}}$) is a good
>   approximation of real $\mu$ and the
>   standard deviation of deltas is
>   connected to the real standard
>   deviation $sigma$ as follows:
>   $\sigma_{\overline{\Delta}} =
> > \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. You will be
>   also able to calculate the 95\%
>   confidence interval of the difference
>   estimate using either Z or t
>   distribution (depending on the number
>   of cases you have measured)
>
> Having all this information you will
>   be able to conclude that B agrees with
>   A within $\mu_{\overline{\Delta}}$
>   with standard deviation of
>   $\sigma_{\overline{\Delta}} \times
> > \sqrt{n}$ or that B agrees with A
>   within $\pm CI_{95\%}$

Is there any reason not to?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to your problem, but the case of quantized data (which you usually got after a measurement) is often treated wrongly in the literature. Take a look at http://www.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Lehrstuehle/MSind/SFB_475/2003/tr39-03.pdf to get an idea of the pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the output is continious.
Whatever you do, don't try calculating the correlation between the methods. I think that the paper ["Statistical methods for assessing agreement between two methods of clinical measurement](http://su.pr/1bbvgI)"  is what you need